# Bokeh DataTable and Bootstrap conflict

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable, bokeh

This image explains the issue pretty well:

[image: Bokeh DataTable with bootstrap]

I believe that Bokeh assumes some information to calculate columns width, and bootstrap is modifying those styles, making headers and inner rows have different column widths.

The width of the columns ends up being an inline style. Removing all bootstrap styles applying to the table doesn't fix the problem, but not loading bootstrap from the very beginning does. Obviously, that's not a solution for me, as I need bootstrap on the rest of the page.

Has anyone come across this?

**Edit**

Code examples reproducing the issue:

- [Python code that creates an html](http://ideone.com/6ybuA2)
- [Fiddle with the produced html/js code](https://jsfiddle.net/mjayd4jt/1/)

The following is the list of js references that Idone doesn't show:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.3.min.css">
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is one obvious value in the average column that is much longer than the others. Does changing it to fewer digits improve things?

Comment: can you post a code example for this?

Comment: Yes. I added some example code reproducing the issue.

Comment: Got the same problem. Heres a workaround till the next version(i.e. 0.12.4) - https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5398